# .htaccess Redirect from sub.domain.com.au* to www.domain.com.au/URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I am attempting to redirect a development site that has been indexed by search engines to a specific category in the new live site.

The development site URL was:

```
http://staging.mydomain.com.au/
```

There are multiple page url's after the domain so I'd like to redirect all of these to the same new URL.

```
E.g.
http://staging.mydomain.com.au/essential_grid/
http://staging.mydomain.com.au/feed/
```

The new url is, where "/portfolio/" is where I need the old URLs redirected to:

```
http:www.mydomain.com.au/portfolio/
```

> While I'm not receiving any error messages, staging.mydomain.com.au is
>   not redirecting to www.mydomain.com.au/portfolio/

This is a snippet of what I have in my .htaccess file at present:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^staging.mydomain.com.au$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com.au/portfolio [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** It seems (from comments) that `staging.` no longer exists - that's the problem! `staging.` needs to exist (ie. the DNS must resolve) so that the request gets to your server in order to do the redirect. If `staging.` does not exist then the initial request will simply fail (the browser will fail to lookup the domain and you'll get a DNS error).

You need to recreate the `staging` subdomain (even with no files) and then implement the redirect below.

---

Your `RewriteRule` actually looks OK - assuming you are wanting to redirect all those URLs to the single `/portfolio` URL. However, the order should perhaps be changed to have the redirect before the internal rewrite. `RewriteEngine` only needs to be included once and you don't need `RewriteBase` in the code you have posted. So, this should be rewritten as:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^staging\.mydomain\.com\.au$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.mydomain.com.au/portfolio [R=301,L]
```

`^(.*)$` is reduced to simply `^` since you don't need to capture the URL for a backreference in the substitution.

I've also removed the other `RewriteRule` as it doesn't appear to be doing anything?

Also note that 301 redirects are cached by the browser, so make sure that you clear your browser cache between failed attempts. It can be easier to test with 302 temporary redirects for this reason.

Comment: Thanks W3d, will give it a try and advise outcome.

Comment: I've implemented the code (as a 302), cleared cache, restarted browser, and it fails to redirect as expected.

Comment: Does it do anything? I assume this .htaccess file is located in the document root of your site? And that `staging.` and `www.` both point to the same place? Is mod_rewrite enabled? Is .htaccess permitted? ie. `AllowOverride` is set appropriately in your server config? Do you have anything else in your .htaccess file? Do you have any other .htaccess files?

Comment: Yes, located in the document root of the site indeed. 
staging. doesn't exist any more - it's only indexed on Google hence the need to redirect.
Will check on mod_rewrite enabled - pretty sure it is
Yes, .htaccess is permitted
There is other code in the .htaccess file yes, and no there are no other .htaccess files.
Thanks for your efforts here w3d. I'll go and take another look.
Appreciate your help.

Comment: "`staging.` doesn't exist any more" - that's the problem! `staging.` needs to exist (ie. the DNS must resolve) so that the request gets to your server in order to do the redirect. If `staging.` does not exist then the initial request will simply fail at the first hurdle. (I'll update my answer.)

Comment: "While I'm not receiving any error messages" - rather puzzled by this. If the subdomain does not exist then either the browser will fail to lookup the DNS and you'll get an error, or the DNS is cached and the server will reject the request? Either way you should be getting an error?